# How do I access multipart form data in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, multipartform-data

I am using Sinatra with Thin.

When trying to get access the contents of a POST request with multipart data, I don't see any convenient way to access this, though it seems I can get to the raw body.

Is there something I am missing? Is there a convenient way to do this, or must I parse the data myself?

`request.env['rack.request.form_hash']` gives an empty hash.

When dumping the body (`request.body.read()`) to stdout, it looks like this:

```
--KoZIhvcNAQcB
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="1"
X-compId: 1
Content-Length: 1024

QeQL4k8RPBQVrP2u8Zf6Ie82labdA_
d7s FgvwSQvkP6e0TwaWWCfoHWbaP6
... (some lines omitted)

--KoZIhvcNAQcB--
```

I also see that it is not a chunked transfer encoding issue (I read that Thin has an issue with that); the Transfer-Encoding header is not set.
But as for my question, does Sinatra or Rack supply something in the API for accessing multipart details?

**UPDATE**: After doing some reading, I see the multipart data is supposed to be visible in the request parameters. As a result, I have logged an issue on GitHub. If I get it resolved, I will post an answer here. https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/695

Comment: what about just printing `params` in your post path?  what does that output?

Comment: I have added some data, but I would like to know whether the APIs of either Sinatra or Rack support something like this, or whether I must parse the multipart/form data myself.

Comment: @dax `params` is showing only the parameters present in the URL path.

Comment: @mydoghasworms can you show how you post against your api that we can play around with it?

Comment: @Sirl33tname Aber sicher. I added a link to a sample to the GitHub issue that I logged: https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/695#issuecomment-44835794

Comment: @Sirl33tname. I have uploaded a portion of the web server log that contains the post request: https://copy.com/ztlGA7QwzyFh